# Amusement parks in the New York City area

Tags: sightseeing, new-york-city, amusement-parks

What are our options for amusement parks in the New York City area? We will be staying in Union City on the other side of Hudson River and may consider a one hour commute (preferrably by public transportation) to an amusement park.

Comment: What will you be using to commute?

Comment: Clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your restrictions on transportation namely public transportation your choices are limited to:

- [Victoria Gardens](http://www.victoriangardensnyc.com/)
- [Luna Park](http://www.lunaparknyc.com/)
- [Adventurers Park](http://www.adventurerspark.com/)

All located in New York City.

Answer (score 2):

[Six Flags Great Adventure](https://www.sixflags.com/greatadventure) is a very large amusement park and perhaps the most obvious choice. Google says it is 1:06 away from Union City by car. There are smaller parks closer to Union City which may be better for younger kids, e.g. [Bowcraft](http://www.bowcraft.com/rides-attractions.php). Your choice depends a bit on your group...